# Any One having any idea how to change the color of button not cell in Swift Forms

Tags: swift, forms, uicolor

[image]I want to change the color of button in cell. when i tried to change hole cell color was changed. Even i want the click event only on button not on cell. I want to validate my textfield also like email validation. How to add validation in textfield.
Please help me . Thanks in advance. I am using this link -https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms

Comment: search the cell subviews to get the textfield then change its color?

Comment: Swift form is libary. i am getting any cell.

Comment: Are you adding this button inside tableView?